# How to secure the use of a PFX with a PHP code

Tags: php, pfx

I need to make a cURL with PHP and for the target domain of the cURL I have to pass a PFX, which is protected by a password.
But I find it very insecure to have the certificate's password in the PHP code or in an environment variable.

I've seen that I can extract the CRT and private key from the PFX, but it still doesn't seem very secure to me.

Unfortunately I cannot ask for the PFX password when a user performs the cURL operation as it is hidden from the user.

What would be the best option to secure the certificate?

I extracted the private key and certificate like this:

```
#Extract Private Key
openssl pkcs12 -in originalpfx.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes

#Extract Certificate
openssl pkcs12 -in originalpfx.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.crt
```

Comment: "I find it very insecure to have the certificate's password in [...] an environment variable." Why?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica If someone manages to get access to the PFX and the password, he can do many operations on behalf of the company.
Because this type of certificate is to identify the company in government agencies.

Comment: _"If someone manages to get access to the PFX and the password,"_ How? If someone can access the source code on the server, he can do more other operations than this, so secure your server.